# Is mass up- and downvoting detection also available on StackExchanges?

Tags: support, abuse

A UTC midnight after this happened: (I gained 90 rep in 15 minutes, I made this screenshot in between)

[image]

...I still have the 90 rep I gained this way. What's going on?

Comment: I could freehand circle, but then I'd have to freehand circle the entire thing.

Comment: you could circle each vote separately

Comment: I think you may have just hit a wave of new people digging through tags and questions and up voting what they like.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a freehand chain then, @Tobias?

Comment: just draw many many free hand circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the system may have changed, but a few months ago I've done some testing and this is what I inferred:

- The system checks at **midnight UTC** if the same person upvoted or downvoted you 5 or more times.
- If not, nothing happens.
- If yes, the votes are canceled.

Since the script runs only once a day, the results are not instantaneous.

Comment: 5 is a very low limit, I often look at all quesions/answers by someone with a common interest to me and upvote the good ones.

Comment: @Ian: I don't disagree, but that's what I observed when I did my testing with throw away accounts. I also tried on a stack exchange 1.0 where I was admin, and it was the same. I may have done something wrong and I can't say I'm 100% certain, but I am highly confident I've done the testing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in beta the serial-vote mechanism is less sensitive. Also, you can't tell whether all the votes were made by the same person, it could just be coincidence. (Like in 1:3600 or so, but it has to happen *some* time)